# Converting data into time series

Tags: r

I have a small problem concerning conversion of data to time series.
Here are the steps that i carried out.
My data ranges from 21 January 2014 to 28 February 2019 and comprises of colnames Price and Date.

1.I imported the data from excel using read.csv().

```
interest<-read.csv("C:/Users/Kane/interest.csv", stringsAsFactors=F, header=T)
```

data length=1146

2.There were some missing dates and missing values. I applied na_interpolation().

```
library("imputeTS")
interest<-na_interpolation(interest$Price)
```

data length becomes 1864

3.I computed the returns using diff(log(interest$Price))

```
returns<-diff(log(interest$Price))
```

4.I converted the returns to time series.

```
return.ts<-ts(data=returns,frequency=365,start=c(2014,1), end=c(2019,2))
```

data length became 1832.

Can i get an explanation upon why upon conversion to timeseries, the data legth decreased drastically and a solution please.

The sample of my data:

```
> interest
       Date    Price
1    2014-01-22 3.820000
2    2014-01-23 3.802857
3    2014-01-24 3.785714
4    2014-01-25 3.768571
5    2014-01-26 3.751429
6    2014-01-27 3.734286


> dput(head(interest))
structure(list(Date = structure(c(16092, 16093, 16094, 16095, 
16096, 16097), class = "Date"), Price = c(3.82, 3.80285714285714, 
3.78571428571429, 3.76857142857143, 3.75142857142857, 3.73428571428571
)), .Names = c("Date", "Price"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Results when converting return to ts:

```
> return1<-ts(Return,frequency=365,start=c(2014,1),end=c(2019,2))
> length(return1)
[1] 1827
> return<-ts(Return,frequency=365,start=c(2014,1),end=c(2018,11))
> length(return)
[1] 1471
> return<-ts(Return,frequency=365,start=c(2014,1),end=c(2018,12))
> length(return)
[1] 1472
```

Comment: hi please provide a small sample of your data so we can better understand your problem.
The best way of doing this is to post the output of `dput(head(interest))` in your question.

Comment: @Cettt Hi,i carrried out what you told me to do, i edited my question and included the output

Comment: In your step 1, the data length of `interest` is 1146.  After you perform `na.interpolation()` you say that your data length becomes 1864.  Is this correct?  I imagine these data lengths refer to the length of a particular column, correct?

Comment: @VictorMaxwell Yes, it became 1864 as there were missing dates. After i added the missing date, then i performed na.interpolation for the price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you're asking, but maybe this helps. I've used your sample data, and clearly you have not missed in them, so the first step should skip (also, you have not given us the package of the `na.interpolation`).

However, here your data:

```
       Date    Price
1 2014-01-22 3.820000
2 2014-01-23 3.802857
3 2014-01-24 3.785714
4 2014-01-25 3.768571
5 2014-01-26 3.751429
6 2014-01-27 3.734286
```

Now, adding the `diff` function is going to make the data with one less observation:

```
returns
[1] -0.004497759 -0.004518080 -0.004538586 -0.004559278 -0.004580161
```

You can apply the `ts` function now, and adding the start with the first day, being a daily time series:

```
 ts(data=returns,frequency=365,start = decimal_date(as.Date("2014-01-22")))
Time Series:
Start = c(2014, 22) 
End = c(2014, 26) 
Frequency = 365 
[1] -0.004497759 -0.004518080 -0.004538586 -0.004559278 -0.004580161
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked really fine for me.